# Adding variable to an href ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to add the result of `Request.QueryString('x')` (VB script) to an href as shown below:

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Reports/ProductionReport.aspx?SiteCode=<%=Request.QueryString('SiteCode')%>">Production Details</a>
```

There is something wrong with my syntax, but I can't figure out what. If I click the link, it redirects me to a page that is:

```
"~/Reports/ProductionReport.aspx?SiteCode=<%=Request.QueryString('SiteCode')%>"
```

instead of `"~/Reports/ProductionReport.aspx?SiteCode=value"`

Could someone give me the correct syntax?

Comment: Besides the problem with the markup you the `~` will be replaced only by server controls, like a Linkbutton or an HyperLink, you won't be able to use it in an `a`, so, when you change that to a ServerControl you will be able to set the NavigateUrl from the server side

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `runat="server"` tag if you don't need it.

```
 <a href="/Reports/ProductionReport.aspx?SiteCode=<%= Request.QueryString("SiteCode") %>">Production Details</a>
```

Or create a HyperLink Control and set the `NavigateUrl` from code behind

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Production Details</asp:HyperLink>

HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "/Reports/ProductionReport.aspx?SiteCode=" + Request.QueryString("SiteCode")
```